# Retrieving files stored on Windows 8 Device from "Metro" app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to be able to allow my users to select photos and video stored on their Windows Phones from within my Windows 8 (Metro) Store app. I'm not sure if this is possible, but since the Windows Phone behaves as a USB-drive-like devide when plugged in via USB, I am assuming it is no different from any other `Remote Storage`.

Is there a way to access this location programmatically, without opening a Picker, so that the process can be somewhat automated if they so choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are predefined pickers

here is the example for a file picker using images. But be aware 
ff the user chooses a file outside of your permissionscope (from example desktop) only the StorageFile instance which is returned from the picker has the rights to be accessed.

So you should keep that alive as long as you do something with that file. or you copy it locally

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<IStorageFile> FileFromPicker(string identity)
    {
        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();

        setFileTypes(picker);

        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SettingsIdentifier = identity;

        var storageFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        return storageFile;
    }
```